# Bulk replacing statements in ontotext GraphDB

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb

I am currently working on integrating with ontotext's GraphDB using their RDF4J API.

I am trying to insert and replace large sets of statements, ideally in one go. I am currently doing this on my Fuseki instance (which I'm migrating away from) by creating this block for every triple I want to insert into my Graph (currently only using default graph) and submitting that as one `update` call using semi-colons to separate the statements (where that is going into the `post` body);

```
delete { <x:test> <y:name> ?o } 
insert { <x:test> <y:name> "Test" } 
where { optional{ <x:test> <y:name> ?o }};
delete { <x:test> <y:description> ?o } 
insert { <x:test> <y:description> "Test" } 
where { optional{ <x:test> <y:description> ?o }};
delete { <x:test2> <y:name> ?o } 
insert { <x:test2> <y:name> "Test" } 
where { optional{ <x:test2> <y:name> ?o }};
```

I have been looking at the API and as far as I can work out Statement Post Method (`POST /repositories/{repositoryID}/statement`) only allows a SPARQL 1.1 Update string like that in the query parameter called **`update`**.

This means I would end up appending thousands of these blocks of SPARQL onto the query parameter which really doesn't feel right.

Am I missing something with how you update statements in GraphDB? Is there a better strategy I should be following?

### EDIT 1

After a play around I've created the following which seems to work however I can't say whether or not it would be considered a good way of doing it;

```
DELETE {
   <x:test> ?p ?o
}
WHERE {
    <x:test> ?p ?o . 
        VALUES (?p) {
          (<y:name>) 
          (<y:description>)
        } 
};
INSERT DATA {
    <x:test> <y:name> "New Name" .
    <x:test> <y:description> "New Description" .
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,
John

Comment: It should be possible to put multiple queries into a single query string.

Comment: As an alternative to Jeen Broekstra's (excellent) answer, you could probably use `VALUES` in the `WHERE` clause. E. g. `WHERE { ?s ?p ?o . VALUES (?s ?p) {(:test1 :name1) (:test2 :name2)} }` or (which is not the same) `WHERE { ?s ?p ?o . VALUES (?s) {(:test1) (:test2)} . VALUES (?p) {(:name1) (:name2)} }`.

Comment: Hi @StanislavKralin, just to confirm are you saying to do something like this.... 
DELETE { 
 ?s ?p ?o 
} 
INSERT { 
 <x:test> <y:name> "New Name" .
 <x:test> <y:description> "New Description" .
} 
WHERE { 
 ?s ?p ?o . 
 VALUES (?s ?p) {
  (:test :name) 
  (:test :description)
 } 
}

Comment: @JohnBartlett, I mean rather `INSERT {?s ?p "New Name" . ?s ?p "New Description"}`, but it depends on what you want...

Comment: @StanislavKralin, I would want to replace the existing triples with the new triples in the insert (so that only one name and description exist for that subject). So more like this? DELETE { 
 ?s ?p ?o 
} 
INSERT { 
 ?s ?p "New Name" .
 ?s ?p "Old Name" .
} 
WHERE { 
 ?s ?p ?o . 
 VALUES (?s ?p) {
  (:test :name) 
  (:test :description)
 } 
}

Comment: @JohnBartlett great that you found a solution. But please, don't put the solution in your question - instead, post it as an answer (and then accept it). That way it's much clearer for other people with a similar issue to figure out what the solution is.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra, sorry I was not really posting a solution I was just illustrating that I thought this might be better than my original block of sparql per triple. I am still questioning whether or not this is the best approach though?

Comment: Then you need to clarify what you mean with 'best approach '. What part of the solution you found is unsatisfactory?

Comment: For me the solution above is adequate however I'm quite new to this area and was just looking for any kind of best practice for replacing triples in GraphDB. I have been searching around and I cannot seem to see much resembling best practice (but that isn't saying there isn't anything).
Incidentally when trying my "solution" above with larger data sets it broke, on the face of it it appears you cannot supply large volumes of changes via the update query parameter of POST /repositories/{repositoryID}/statement. I will be looking into this in more depth today though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sequence multiple SPARQL updates together using a semicolon, "`;`". For example:

```
delete { <x:test1> <y:name> ?o } 
insert { <x:test1> <y:name> "Test 1" } 
where { <x:test1> <y:name> ?o }};
delete { <x:test2> <y:name> ?o } 
insert { <x:test2> <y:name> "Test 2" } 
where { <x:test2> <y:name> ?o }
```

Just send such a sequence string to the update endpoint and it will be executed in one go.

As for whether this is the most efficient way to do it, that's a different matter. Do the statements that you are trying to replace share any characteristics? If so, it might be possible to express the update in a single query, rather than a sequence for each triple / subject.

Comment: Hi Jeen Broekstra, Thank you for your answer. Yes I am currently using a semi colon to separate 1000's of these statements into the single update query parameter. I suppose the commonality would be more based on the interface being handled at the time. For instance one interface would be loading a subset of information against a subject and therefore it might be possible to say delete all triples for a given subject with that subject of predicates before loading all the new triples. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

After a play around I've created the following which seems to work for what I am after however I can't say whether or not it would be considered "Best Practice" - I will let those more in the know than me comment on that.

```
DELETE {
   <x:test> ?p ?o
}
WHERE {
    <x:test> ?p ?o . 
        VALUES (?p) {
          (<y:name>) 
          (<y:description>)
        } 
};
INSERT DATA {
    <x:test> <y:name> "New Name" .
    <x:test> <y:description> "New Description" .
}
```

There is an issue regarding processing of large amount of updates using the GraphDB API's however I will raise that as a separate issue because if I process these individually (or in small batches) it works perfectly.

Thanks,
John